# Inserting component data using impex?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, insert-update, impex

I am a beginner in the Sap Hybris. I created a new model `BookComponent` from `SimpleCMSComponent`

```
<itemtypes>
        <itemtype code="BookComponent" extends="SimpleCMSComponent" generate="true" autocreate="true"
        jaloclass="com.training.core.jalo.BookComponent">
        <description>Used to display offers on homepage</description>
            <attributes>
                <attribute type="localized:java.lang.String" qualifier="headrerText">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="true" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
                <attribute type="localized:java.lang.String" qualifier="footerText">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="true" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
                <attribute type="Media" qualifier="bookImage">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="false" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>
                <attribute type="BookLinksList" qualifier="bookImageLink">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                    <description>List of CMS Link Component</description>
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" />
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
        </itemtypes>

<collectiontypes>
    <collectiontype code="BookLinksList" 
                   elementtype="CMSLinkComponent" 
                  autocreate="true" generate="true" type="list" />
</collectiontypes>
```

after ant all with success and update, my model is created correctly even in the database with all the attributes as we defined in `trainingcore-items.xml` file.

Then I created some impex to insert my new component as following :

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog 
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
$productCatalog=apparelProductCatalog 
$productCatalogName=Apparel Product Catalog 
$productCV=catalogVersion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged] 
$picture=media(code, $contentCV) ;

$siteResource=jar:de.hybris.platform.apparelstore.constants.ApparelstoreConstants&/apparelstore/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/$contentCatalog
$jarResourceCms=jar:de.hybris.platform.apparelstore.constants.ApparelstoreConstants&/apparelstore/import/sampledata/cockpits/cmscockpit
$category=category(code, $productCV)
$lang=en


INSERT_UPDATE CMSLinkComponent ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; uid[unique=true]     ; name                   ; url                   ; &linkRef             ; &componentRef        ; target(code)[default='sameWindow'] ; $category


                               ;                         ; InformatiqueBookLink ; Informatique Book Link ; /InformatiqueBookLink ; InformatiqueBookLink ; InformatiqueBookLink ;                                    ;          
                               ;                         ; ScienceBookLink      ; Science Book Link      ; /ScienceBookLink      ; ScienceBookLink      ; ScienceBookLink      ;                                    ;          
                               ;                         ; AstroBookLink        ; Astro Book Link        ; /AstroBookLink        ; AstroBookLink        ; AstroBookLink        ;                                    ;          

INSERT_UPDATE Media ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; code[unique=true] ; @media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator] ; mime[default='image/jpeg'] ; &imageRef  ; folder(qualifier)[default='images'] ; altText    
                    ;                         ; bookMedia         ; $siteResource/images/banners/homepage/books.jpeg                           ;                            ; books.jpeg ;                                     ; books.jpeg ;  

INSERT_UPDATE BookComponent ; $contentCV[unique=true] ; uid[unique=true]   ; name            ; headrerText[lang=$lang] ; footerText[lang=$lang] ; bookImage(code) ; &componentRef      ; bookImageLink(&linkRef)                           
                            ;                         ; bookofferComponent ; offer Component ; "Header text"           ; "Footer text"          ; bookMedia       ; bookofferComponent ; InformatiqueBookLink,ScienceBookLink,AstroBookLink
```

but insertion does not pass and on the hac cosnole this message is displayed

```
NSERT_UPDATE BookComponent;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog:Staged][unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;headrerText[lang=en];footerText[lang=en];bookImage(code);&componentRef;bookImageLink(&linkRef)
,,,,Exception : line 29: cannot create BookComponent with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {bookimagelink=[8796256896060, 8796256928828, 8796256961596], uid=bookofferComponent, bookimage=bookMedia(bookMedia(8798226972702)), catalogversion=apparel-ukContentCatalog/Staged(8796093186649), headrertext={8796093055008->en=Header text}, name=offer Component, footertext={8796093055008->en=Footer text}} ] due to [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.MandatoryAttributesValidator@113d6726]:valeurs manquantes pour [footerText, headrerText] dans le modèle BookComponentModel (<unsaved>) pour créer un nouveau BookComponent, Exception : line 3: cannot create BookComponent with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {bookimagelink=[8796256896060, 8796256928828, 8796256961596], uid=bookofferComponent, bookimage=bookMedia(bookMedia(8798226972702)), catalogversion=apparel-ukContentCatalog/Staged(8796093186649), headrertext={8796093055008->en=Header text}, name=offer Component, footertext={8796093055008->en=Footer text}} ] due to [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.MandatoryAttributesValidator@113d6726]:valeurs manquantes pour [footerText, headrerText] dans le modèle BookComponentModel (<unsaved>) pour créer un nouveau BookComponent;;bookofferComponent;offer Component;Header text;Footer text;bookMedia;bookofferComponent;InformatiqueBookLink,ScienceBookLink,AstroBookLink
```

However I add all mandatory fields.
Thank for you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It may be problem with quotes in `"Footer text"`. Try to remove them or escape or replace with single quotes `'Footer text'` or with double double quotes `""Footer text""`.

Comment: I think the first update has not been passed properly, I launched system update again and it works. Thank u for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference medias by code AND catalog version. When you only reference it by code, it will only pass if there is only one media with that specific code in your database. Once you synchronize the apparel-ukContentCatalog there will be two medias with the code "bookMedia" in your database. One in the Staged and one in the Online catalog version. So use:

bookImage(code,$contentCV)